# CardView padding and rounded corners

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-cardview

I am trying to add rounded corners and padding to my card views, corner radius don't seem to work when I have content padding.

This is my current XML:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="71dp"
    android:layout_height="39dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="0dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="false"
    card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="7dp"
    card_view:contentPaddingLeft="4dp"
    card_view:contentPaddingRight="4dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="71dp"
        android:layout_height="39dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:background="#FF9400"
        android:gravity="center" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

If I remove the content padding, then the corner radius works, but I need both.

Anyone have any ideas? I know I can set `cardUseCompatPadding` to true, but then the entire card has padding which messes with the text view.

**EDIT:**

Here is the design I currently have, and what I'm replicating:

[image]

Comment: Use margin instead of padding, take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34581086

Comment: I've tried that too unfortunately, and no margin is actually added for some reason.

Comment: Do you have an UI in mind, could you put like screenshot of what you want to achieve?

Comment: @4k3R Sure! I've updated the question.

Comment: Does setting *marginLeft* and *marginRight* to your `CardView` in XML not work? Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25632756/cardview-has-lost-margin-when-inflating) answer.

Comment: Just a quick question and a suggestion.. why do you need a card view for this.. you can implement this by just creating a drawable xml with rectangle and rounded corners.. and set that drawable as your view's background..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If that's an horizontal `RecyclerView`, add an `ItemDecorator` to it to have some spacing between objects.

```
SpaceItemDecorator itemDecorator = new SpacesItemDecorator(16)
mList.addItemDecoration(itemDecorator);
```

With an `SpaceItemDecorator` similar to this:

```
public class SpacesItemDecorator extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

    private final int space;

    public SpacesItemDecorator(int spaceInPx) {
        this.space = spaceInPx;
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, 
            RecyclerView.State state) {
        outRect.left = space;
        outRect.right = space;
    }
}
```